# Extending NotificationCenter

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter

I am trying to write an extension for `NotificationCenter`

I find the syntax a little meaty and "boilerplatey" and would like to provide a simple extension that simplifies posting and observing.

I can dispatch an event like so

```
NotificationCenter.dispatch(key: <#T##String#>, payload: <#T##[String : String]#>)
```

However I would like to observe an event in a similar fashion.

I am trying to create something like

```
NotificationCenter.observe(key: <#T##String#>, handler: <#T##() -> Void#>)
```

However this is not correct. I am unsure how I can handler passing in my selector function that should be triggered on an observation?

This is my attempt so far.

```
extension NotificationCenter {
    static func dispatch(key: String, payload: [String: String] = [:]) {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: key), object: nil, userInfo: payload)
    }
    static func observe(key: String, handler: ()->Void) {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            self, selector: handler, name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: key), object: nil
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/cesarferreira/SwiftEventBus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need something like

```
extension NotificationCenter {
    static func dispatch(key: String, payload: [String: String] = [:]) {
        self.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: key), object: nil, userInfo: payload)
    }
    static func observe(key: String, handler: @escaping (Notification) -> Void) {
        self.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: key), object: nil, queue: .main, using: handler)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
extension NotificationCenter {

    class func observe(name: NSNotification.Name, handler: @escaping (Notification) -> Void) {
        self.default.addObserver(forName: name, object: nil, queue: .main, using: handler)
    }

}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
NotificationCenter.observe(name: UIResponder.keyboardDidShowNotification) { notification in
    // do something
}
```

You should definitely check out https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notificationcenter/1411723-addobserver regarding unregistering observations though.

Answer (score -1):

NotificationCenter - a useful but bulky looking interface, feels a bit bloating in code, as someone coming from UNIX-like thread synchronization semantics... So, these extensions are based on stuff on S.O. & the 'Net, with a couple of twists.

```
extension Notification.Name {
    static let patientlyWaiting = Notification.Name("patientlyWaiting")
    // .
    // . list your arbitrary waiter names here...
    // .
}
extension NotificationCenter {
    static func wait(_ name : Notification.Name) async {
        for await _ in NotificationCenter.default.notifications(named: name) {
            break;
        }
    }
    static func post(_ name : Notification.Name) {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: name, object: nil)
    }
    static func postProcessing(_ name: Notification.Name, using block: @escaping (Notification) -> Void)  {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: name, object: nil, queue: OperationQueue.main, using: block)
    }
}
```

To use it, something like this:

**Waiting for notification:**

```
@IBAction func doSomethingAsychronouslyButtonPushed(_ sender: Any)  {
    doSomethingAsynchronously()
    NotificationCenter.postProcessing(.patientlyWaiting, using: { _ in
        print("doSomethingAsynchronouslyButton completion handler called")
    })
}
```

**Notifying:**

```
func doSomethingAsynchronously() {
     for n in ["Time", " ",  "consuming", " - ", "whatever"] {
          print("\(n)", terminator: "")
     }
     print("\n")
     NotificationCenter.post(.patientlyWaiting) 
}
```

<sub>*Note: You could avoid using a closure and do an inline wait using Swift language's recently-added `async`/`await` support (see the 'wait()`function in the extensions shown above), but I didn't provide an example of using that because I haven't been able to invoke`async`functions from selectors, such as from a`UIButton`press, directly or indirectly; because, any function that uses`await`needs to be declared`async`. Specifically, #selector(afunc(_:)) doesn't match functions declared` async`, and I'm unaware of a function signature syntax that accounts for an` async`in function declaration (to pass to`#selector()`). If someone knows, let me know in the comments and I'll update the answer.*</sub>